# Twig uses htmlspecialchars internally for escaping. How do I pass ENT_NOQUOTES?

Tags: twig

I'm using Twig for an embedded application that renders a basic subset of HTML. However, it does not support `&quot;` for double quotes, and simply shows `quot;` instead of `"`.

[image: A screen with misrendered HTML entities]

I want to achieve the equivalent of

```
htmlspecialchars($input_string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Twig's documentation says that it uses htmlspecialchars internally for its escaping. How do I set this flag when escaping a particular string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom  [escaping strategy](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html).

Create a new escaping strategy called `html_no_quotes` as follows:

```php
$twig
    ->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::class)
    ->setEscaper('html_no_quotes', function($twig_environment, $string, $charset) {
        return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
    })
;
```

Then inside your template use your `html_no_quotes` escaping strategy as follows:

```
{{ someString | escape('html_no_quotes') }}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and accept this if that works. Surprised it's not a built-in thing, ahah.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is more suitable:

```
{{ someString | raw }}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html